# How to add a javascript variable to javascript src. Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

To sum up, I have a variable (hiragana path), that is responsible of helding the path of each image. The main issue is that the path of each image depends on the random imagel label. That's why I cannot just type in every path. The solution to this is assigning a variable (hiragana path). But at the time of putting it to work, in Jquery I could not put a variable in the src. Any Help?

'''

```
    var hiragana_img

    var hiragana_letter

    var hiragana_all= ['a','i','e','o','u']

    var hiragana_list = {"vowels_list": ['a','i','e','o','u'],

    "ka_list": ['ka','ki','ke','ko','ku']
    };





    function random_hiragana(hiragana_letter, hiragana_all){

        hiragana_letter = hiragana_all.random();

        var hiragana_path = "../../proyect_images/hiragana_v/" + hiragana_letter + ".png"



        $('#core').append("<img id='hiragana_img' src='hiragana_path'/>")
        return true;
```

''''

Comment: You have to concatenate the variable in the string ... `src='" + hiragana_path + "'`

Comment: I've tried, but it prompts an error

Comment: What is the specific error?

Comment: `hiragana_all.random();` looks fishy. Arrays don't have  a random() method

Comment: Really?, there's any way I could randomize it?

Comment: Doing as you typed, it does not prompt any error, my bad.

Comment: Yes you can write code to randomize it. Easy web search

Comment: Thanks man. Good to know I was doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with OP's code:

1. End each line with a semi-colon `;`
2. `hiragana_letter` is declared then defined *after* being passed through the function.
3. `hiragana_list` is defined then never used.
4. The method `.random()` cannot be suffixed to an array.
5. When concatenating literal strings you must

   1. use either single or double quotes to wrap the entire string.
   2. use the opposite quotes to wrap anything within the string.
   3. use the same type of quotes in step 5.1 and then the plus character `+` to wrap any variable inserted into a string.

   ```
   var path = "https://domainName.dot/img.png";  
   var htmlString = "<img src='"+path+"'>";
   ```

The demo below will:

1. pass an array of strings `vowels`
2. generate a random index number in the range of 0 to 4  `random`

   ```
   var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
   ```
3. apply both to get a string `vowels[random]`

   ```
   vowels[2] = 'e'
   ```
4. insert the string into a string representing a url `path`

   ```
   var path = "../../proyect_images/hiragana_v/k" + vowels[random] + ".png"

   "../../proyect_images/hiragana_v/ke.png"
   ```

   **Note:** "k" was prefixed to the image file name because I noticed that the unused object `hiragana_list` had an array of vowels prefixed with a "k". BTW arrays are not keyed with strings like: `"vowels_list":` or `"ka_list":` in JavaScript.
5. Appends htmlString to `.core` (try to use class if you are using jQuery, id will just limit your code unless you are dealing with form controls.)
6. returns the path so it can be checked in the console. 99% of the time if a function isn't returning a value, it's returning `false`

```js
var vowels = ['a', 'i', 'e', 'o', 'u'];

function hiragana(vowels) {
  var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
  var path = "../../proyect_images/hiragana_v/k" + vowels[random] + ".png"
  $('.core').append("<img src='" + path + "'>");
  return path;
};

console.log(hiragana(vowels));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class='core'></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: I think arrays don't have `random()` method to get a random value from hiragana_all try:

```
hiragana_letter = hiragana_all[Math.floor(Math.random() * hiragana_all.length)];
```

Second: to use `hiragana_path` as a varaible use `+` character to concatenate

```
function random_hiragana(hiragana_letter, hiragana_all) {
    hiragana_letter = hiragana_all[Math.floor(Math.random() * hiragana_all.length)];

    var hiragana_path = "../../proyect_images/hiragana_v/" + hiragana_letter + ".png"
    $('#core').append("<img id='hiragana_img' src='" + hiragana_path + "'/>")

    return true;
}
```